# Flattening a binary search tree into a list

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

```
typedef struct node *blah;

int *breath_search(struct node *root){

    int *numbers = calloc(20,sizeof(*numbers)); int listpointer = 0;
    struct node **currentlist = calloc(20,sizeof(struct node*));
    struct node **updatedlist = calloc(20,sizeof(struct node*));
    currentlist[0] = root;
    int iterations = 1;

    int depths = 3;
    while(depths){


        int i = 0; int j;
        for(j=0;j<iterations;j++){
            if(currentlist[j] == NULL){
                updatedlist[i] = NULL; i++;
                updatedlist[i] = NULL; i++;
                numbers[listpointer] = 0; listpointer++;
            }
            else if(currentlist[j] != NULL){
                updatedlist[i] = currentlist[j]->left; i++;
                updatedlist[i] = currentlist[j]->right; i++;
                numbers[listpointer] = (int) alpabatise(currentlist[j]->newitem.key); listpointer++;
            }
        }

        currentlist = updatedlist;
        updatedlist = (blah[])     {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
        iterations = iterations*2;

        depths--;

    }

    return numbers;
}
```

I've been looking at this code for hours and it doesn't make sense why it doesn't work.
I intend to give the function a node and it would return back to me a pointer a list containing all the numbers in the binary tree.

My binary tree is like

```
        231
     /      \
    82      247
   /  \     /  \
  80  137 NULL 263
```

My function only returns back a pointer to list

```
231,82,247,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I expected

```
231,82,247,80,137,0,263,0,0,0,0,0,0...
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it is trying to process any of the nodes below root?

Comment: I have a list of nodes`current list` (initially the root) then i store all nodes left and right of those nodes in the `updated list` this new updated list then becomes the `current list` and it keeps going each time making a `current list` with all nodes below the previous depth,unless my logic is wrong

Comment: I haven't looked at it much but to retrieve that list, you can simply perform an 'Inorder Traversal' and append the data in the list.

Comment: Does this compile?? The line `updatedlist = (blah[])     {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};` I don't think this shall compile. I tried something just like this, and it doesn't compile. Check this :: http://ideone.com/ahyPcm Instead of allocating a new array to `updatedList` try to `calloc` the updating list again

Comment: @user007 HELL YES! it worked thank you! but i have no idea why that line caused an error,I'm just initialising them all to NULL, i shall remember that.Also can you make your comment an answer so i could vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the error in your code is the line ::

```
updatedlist = (blah[]) {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

which I doubt is a valid syntax. Since, you are trying to allocate a new array where you can save the children of the node you just visited, it would be advisable to `calloc` a new array, which you can then use in your code.

So, the line mentioned above shall be change to this ::

```
updatedlist = calloc(20,sizeof(struct node*));
```

A few points which you shall take in consideration, while allocating so much memory is, to free the memory which is no longer of use, since C does not do that explicitly for you, you need to take care of that yourself, so as to avoid any memory leaks.
Since, after every iteration of the `while` loop, the `currentList` is useless, you shall add a statement (before assigning `updatedList` to `currentList`)

```
free(currentList);
```

And at the end of the program freeing the `updatedList` as well.

Secondly, what you are currently doing is something like the level-order traversal of the binary tree. So, you can possibly try using an STL `queue`, and there would be no need to create and swap arrays like you are doing. Something like this ::

```
int *breath_search(struct node *root){

    int *numbers = calloc(20,sizeof(*numbers));
    int listpointer = 0;
    queue<node*> q;
    q.push(root);
    int iterations = 1;

    int depths = 3;
    while(depths){
        int i = 0, j;
        for(j=0; j<iterations; j++){
            node* currentNode = q.pop();
            if(currentNode == NULL){
                q.push(NULL);
                q.push(NULL);
                numbers[listpointer] = 0;
                listpointer++;
            }
            else if(currentNode != NULL){
                q.push(currentNode->left);
                q.push(currentNode->right);
                numbers[listpointer] = (int) alpabatise(currentlist[j]->newitem.key);
                listpointer++;
            }
        }
        iterations = iterations*2;
        depths--;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

I believe this would be a much better approach to do it, since you do not have to keep on allocating and freeing memory, so it lessens that overhead. I used STL queue, you can definitely use your own queue.